# Thingsboard Can we process the recieved telemetry data and again store computed value

Tags: iot, telemetry, thingsboard

Thingsboard Can we process the recieved telemetry data and again store computed value?

Example if some kind of sensors sending me a x,y,z value as telemetry data and using x,y,z  I have to calculte p=x+y/z and again save p as telemetrey data.

How can i achive this in thingsboard?

Answer (score 0):

"Webscale" solution recommended by Thingsboard: use Apache Spark. A tutorial is available at https://thingsboard.io/docs/samples/analytics/spark-integration-with-thingsboard/

Less complex and less scalable solution (but probably sufficient for many use cases): Program the business logic in a programming language of your choice (Python, Javascript, ...). Let the program subscribe to Thingsboard data through MQTT. Whenever there is a message with x,y,z, perform the calculation and submit p through MQTT. Documentation of Thingsboard's MQTT API: https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/

Alternative: Process the data *before* sending it to Thingsboard. I do this using Google Apps script. The flow goes like this: Sigfox backend -> Google Apps Script -> Thingsboard gateway.

Comment: Note that [ThingsBoard's API only supports subscribing to `attributes` not `telemetry`](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/#subscribe-to-attribute-updates-from-the-server).

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar task yesterday. Thanks to the input from Mikael for an alternative solution I solved it using his proposed flow.

thethingsnetwork --> Google Apps Script --> Thingsboard telemetry data upload

before I used putsreq.com to fiddle with telemetry data but the availability/reliability was not what I was expecting.